# Change Background Of Div Once Contact Form 7 Is Submitted

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

So I'm trying to add a class to the container (.right-side-product-page) and the h2 on a contact 7 form.  Here's a link:

https://nameplicity.com/domains/miningaid/

The goal is to change the class so the blue background and gray background become white, but only after an offer is submitted.

I've tried to add CSS and JavaScript, but can't seem to get anything working.  Here is the code I've tried to use in the "Additional Settings" section under the Contact Form 7 plugin:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
if ( '19533' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
var theDropDown = document.querySelector(".right-side-product-page");
theDropDown.classList.add("MyClass");
}, false );
```

Could anyone provide direction as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: use jquery to change the class

Comment: While I agree that jQuery is great, it isn't the answer to everything @Shohel. The OP was just missing a curly bracket in his code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an error in your code: you're missing one curly bracket in there.

Try this:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
    if ( '19533' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
        var theDropDown = document.querySelector(".right-side-product-page");
        theDropDown.classList.add("MyClass");
    }
}, false );
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to select multiple classes?  So if I wanted to add the class to .right-side-product-page, as well as .offer-container and the H2?

Comment: Hey @BillyW, I've updated the code to include the script tags (wasn't aware you didn't know you needed them :P). Regarding your other question, yes you can add new classes to other elements just in the same way you did in your code - However I don't think you need to, but explaining why here in the comments section would be a bit difficult.

Comment: If you're trying to give a different style to the H2 tag and to `.offer-container`, then you can do so via CSS, for example: `.MyClass h2, .MyClass .offer-container { background: red; }` would change the background color of these two elements to red whenever `.right-side-product-page` has the class `MyClass`. Hope that's clear enough.

Comment: The power of CSS, my friend @BillyW :P Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the error which was mentioned above, you can further complete your solution based on the class added to the `wpcp7-response-output` block, upon successfully sending the message, the `wpcf7-mail-sent-ok` class is added. Knowing this, we can utilize these classes with a check, here's an example:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var outputBlock = $(".wpcf7-response-output");
    var theDropDown = document.querySelector(".right-side-product-page");
    $( ".wpcf7-submit" ).click(function() {
        //Start an interval check after submit has been clicked
        var intervalCheck = setInterval(function () {
            if (outputBlock.hasClass("wpcf7-mail-sent-ok")) {
                // The form has been submitted successfully, set the class to the block to change color
                theDropDown.classList.add("MyClass");
                // Stop running the interval checker after class has been added
                clearInterval(intervalCheck);
            }
        },1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
document.querySelector('.wpcf7-form').addEventListener('submit', function (ev) {
    if(this['_wpcf7'].value == '19533') {
        document.querySelector(".right-side-product-page").classList.add("MyClass");
    }
});
```

or

```
document.querySelector('.wpcf7-form').addEventListener('wpcf7submit', function (ev) {
    if(this['_wpcf7'].value == '19533') {
        document.querySelector(".right-side-product-page").classList.add("MyClass");
    }
}, false);
```

One of them should work. I believe the issue is that the event `wpcf7submit` you're listening to does not exist on document. It exists on document.querySelector('.wpcf7-form').

Comment: "I believe the issue is that the event `wpcf7submit` you're listening to does not exist on document." That's not correct, @mmdts. From [Contact Form 7's DOM API documentation](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/): "Since **all of the wpcf7* events bubble up through a DOM tree toward the document root**, if you don’t need to set a specific event target, you can make it simpler by setting the document property as the event target".

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Had to put it right under the submit button and encase it in  tags.  Thank you everyone for your help!!!